# Projecting the velocity on the line of sight - EDITED

Tags: python, performance, multidimensional-array, average, astronomy

I have a huge text file which contains the position (`x`,`y`,`z`) and velocity component (`vx`,`vy`,`vz`) of a million stars. After doing some rotations and projections, I obtain new position and velocity component (`x'`,`y'`,`z'`,`vx'`,`vy'`,`vz'`) of the stars.

My final step is to compute the velocity along the line of sight, it's like I have to "average" the `vz` component, and to do this I try to create a FITS file in which every pixel contain the mean value of the `vz` component.

Here there's a part of my code:

```
mod = np.genfromtxt('data_bar_region.txt')

x = list(mod[:,0])
y = list(mod[:,1])
vz = mod[:,5]

x_rang_1 = np.arange(-40, 41, 1)
y_rang_1 = np.arange(-40, 41, 1)

fake_data_1 = np.array((len(x_rang_1),len(x_rang_1)))

for i in range(len(x_rang_1)-1):
    for j in range(len(y_rang_1)-1):
        vel_tmp = []
        for index in range(len(x)):
            if x_rang_1[i] <= x[index] <= x_rang_1[i+1]:
                if y_rang_1[j] <= y[index] <= y_rang_1[j+1]:
                    vel_tmp.append(vz[index])
        fake_data_1[j,i] = np.mean(vel_tmp)
            

hdu1 = fits.PrimaryHDU(fake_data_1)
hdu1.writeto('TEST.fits')
```

This code is too much slow (it took about 8 hours on my laptop) and I don't know how I can speed up.

Did you have some suggestions or other ways to compute the `v_LOS` in a better and faster way?

---

EDIT : Before performing the "averaging", I have to divide the image into portions of several shape and dimensions (such portions are called "bins").

Here there's an [image of the bins (on the right panel, there's the same image of bins but it's zoomed to better evidence what are bins)] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVLHr.jpg).

So, I have another FITS file (called bins.fits) with the same dimension of `fake_data_1`, and I just want to find the correspondence between these 2 files, because I want to calculate the mean and the std of the distribution of stars in the several bins.

Alternatively, I have a text file which contains the info on which pixel belongs to a specific bin, for example:

x    y     bin 
1    1      34 
1    2      34 
1    3      34 
.    .       . 
34   56     37 
34   57     37 
34   58     37

and so on. The bins.file has the size (564,585), and so, also the fake_data_1, changing opportunity the start and stop of x and y range. I attached the whole script:

```
mod = np.genfromtxt('data_new_bar_scaled.txt')

# to match the correct position and size of the observation,
# I have to multiply by a factor equal to the semi-size
x = mod[:, 0]*(585-1)/200
y = mod[:, 1]*(564-1)/200
vz = mod[:,5]

A = fits.open('NGC4277_TESIkinematic.fits')
bins = A[7].data.T


start_x = -(585-1)/2
stop_x = (585-1)/2
step_x = step  # step in x_rang_1
x_rang = np.arange(start_x, stop_x + step_x, step_x)    

start_y = -(564-1)/2
stop_y = (564-1)/2
step_y = step  # step in y_rang_1
y_rang = np.arange(start_y, stop_y + step_y, step_y)

fake_data_1 = np.empty((len(x_rang), len(y_rang)))
fake_data_1[:] = np.NaN  # initialize with NaN

 
print(fake_data_1.shape)
print(bins.shape)


d = {}
for i in range(len(x)):
    index_for_x = math.floor((x[i] - start_x) / step_x)
    index_for_y = math.floor((y[i] - start_y) / step_y)
    if 0 <= index_for_x < len(x_rang) and 0 <= index_for_y < len(y_rang):
        key = (x_rang[index_for_x], y_rang[index_for_y]) 
        
        if key in d:
            d[key].append(vz[i])
        else:
            d[key] = [vz[i]]

bb = np.unique(bins)
print(len(bb))

for i, x in enumerate(x_rang):
    for j, y in enumerate(y_rang):
        key = (x, y) 
    
        for z in range(len(bb)):
            j,k = np.where(bb[z]==bins)
            print('index :', z)
            if key in d:
                fake_data_1[j,k] = np.mean(d[key])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is so slow since the nested loops in your code iterate over a million of stars 1600 (80*80) times. You can improve the performance by using a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) and iterating over a million of stars just once.

You can try the following code, which is about 1600 times faster:

```py
import numpy as np
import math

mod = np.genfromtxt('data_bar_region.txt')

x = list(mod[:, 0])
y = list(mod[:, 1])
vz = mod[:, 5]

x_rang_1 = np.arange(-40, 41, 1)
y_rang_1 = np.arange(-40, 41, 1)

fake_data_1 = np.empty((len(x_rang_1), len(y_rang_1)))
fake_data_1[:] = np.NaN  # initialize with NaN

d = {}
for i in range(len(x)):
    key = (math.floor(x[i]), math.floor(y[i]))
    if key in d:
        d[key].append(vz[i])
    else:
        d[key] = [vz[i]]

for i, x in enumerate(x_rang_1):
    for j, y in enumerate(y_rang_1):
        key = (x, y)
        if key in d:
            fake_data_1[i, j] = np.mean(d[key])

hdu1 = fits.PrimaryHDU(fake_data_1)
hdu1.writeto('TEST.fits')
```

---

**UPDATE**

For a generalized version for `step` in `x_rang_1` (or `y_rang_1`), you can try the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import math

mod = np.genfromtxt('data_bar_region.txt')

x = list(mod[:, 0])
y = list(mod[:, 1])
vz = mod[:, 5]

start_x_rang_1 = -40
stop_x_rang_1 = 40
step_x_rang_1 = 0.5  # step in x_rang_1
x_rang_1 = np.arange(start_x_rang_1, stop_x_rang_1 + step_x_rang_1, step_x_rang_1)

start_y_rang_1 = -40
stop_y_rang_1 = 40
step_y_rang_1 = 1  # step in y_rang_1
y_rang_1 = np.arange(start_y_rang_1, stop_y_rang_1 + step_y_rang_1, step_y_rang_1)

fake_data_1 = np.empty((len(x_rang_1), len(y_rang_1)))
fake_data_1[:] = np.NaN  # initialize with NaN

d = {}
for i in range(len(x)):
    index_for_x_rang_1 = math.floor((x[i] - start_x_rang_1) / step_x_rang_1)
    index_for_y_rang_1 = math.floor((y[i] - start_y_rang_1) / step_y_rang_1)
    if 0 <= index_for_x_rang_1 < len(x_rang_1) and 0 <= index_for_y_rang_1 < len(y_rang_1):
        key = (x_rang_1[index_for_x_rang_1], y_rang_1[index_for_y_rang_1])
        if key in d:
            d[key].append(vz[i])
        else:
            d[key] = [vz[i]]

for i, x in enumerate(x_rang_1):
    for j, y in enumerate(y_rang_1):
        key = (x, y)
        if key in d:
            fake_data_1[i, j] = np.mean(d[key])

hdu1 = fits.PrimaryHDU(fake_data_1)
hdu1.writeto('TEST.fits')
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

Maybe like the following?

When I supposed the inputs are

```
x    y    vz
0    0.1  10
1.8  0    4
1.2  1.9  5.2
```

```py
bins = np.array(
    [[34, 35, 34, 34, 36],
     [37, 36, 34, 35, 36],
     [34, 35, 37, 36, 34]])  # shape: (5, 3)
```

You want the following code?

```py
import numpy as np
import math

x = np.array([0, 1.8, 1.2, ])
y = np.array([0.1, 0, 1.9, ])
vz = np.array([10, 4, 5.2])

start_x_rang_1 = 0
stop_x_rang_1 = 2
step_x_rang_1 = 1  # step in x_rang_1
x_rang_1 = np.arange(start_x_rang_1, stop_x_rang_1 + step_x_rang_1, step_x_rang_1)

start_y_rang_1 = 0
stop_y_rang_1 = 0.5
step_y_rang_1 = 2  # step in y_rang_1
y_rang_1 = np.arange(start_y_rang_1, stop_y_rang_1 + step_y_rang_1, step_y_rang_1)

fake_data_1 = np.empty((len(x_rang_1), len(y_rang_1)))  # shape: (3, 5)
fake_data_1[:] = np.NaN  # initialize with NaN
bins = np.array(
    [[34, 35, 34, 34, 36],
     [37, 36, 34, 35, 36],
     [34, 35, 37, 36, 34]])  # shape: (3, 5)

d_bins = {}
for i in range(len(x)):
    index_for_x_rang_1 = math.floor((x[i] - start_x_rang_1) / step_x_rang_1)
    index_for_y_rang_1 = math.floor((y[i] - start_y_rang_1) / step_y_rang_1)
    if 0 <= index_for_x_rang_1 < len(x_rang_1) and 0 <= index_for_y_rang_1 < len(y_rang_1):
        key = bins[index_for_x_rang_1, index_for_y_rang_1]
        if key in d_bins:
            d_bins[key].append(vz[i])
        else:
            d_bins[key] = [vz[i]]

d_bins_mean = {}
for bin in d_bins:
    d_bins_mean[bin] = np.mean(d_bins[bin])

get_corresponding_mean = np.vectorize(lambda x: d_bins_mean.get(x, np.NaN))
result = get_corresponding_mean(bins)
print(result)
```

which prints

```
[[10.   nan 10.  10.   nan]
 [ 4.6  nan 10.   nan  nan]
 [10.   nan  4.6  nan 10. ]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now it is really fast! I want to ask you another thing: I try to change the step in my x_rang_1, for example (-40,40+step, step), but when I use a step equal to 0.5 and show the image I have some problems in the visualization. How can I fix it?

Comment: I need again your help: I tried to modify the code you wrote because I want to introduce a "mask". I have a 2D file with the same dimension of fake_data which contain the positions of the pixels which belong to the same bin.
I have to do this step before calculating the mean of the distribution. I don't know if it is clear, maybe I have to open another question.

Comment: @K.B. In your comment, at the part "which belong to the same bin", what is "bin"?

Comment: I edited the question, hope you can visualize the image.

Comment: @K.B. Thanks! Can you post the example data in the file “bins.fits” and an example way which shows how we can use the data to mask something? I’m not an expert in astronomy so it may help if I can see an example.

Comment: I edited again the question, hope it is clarifying.

Comment: @K.B. Still I'm not sure what you want but I tried something based on my speculation. Please check the updated answer. And if it is not what you want, could you please specify the output you want to get if the inputs are like in "**UPDATE 2**" in my answer?

Comment: My output should be a 2D array with shape (5,3) according to your example, in each pixel of a bin, (so, for example, all the pixels in which bins is equal to 34) should be the mean of the number of stars which fall in all the pixels of the bin (for example, I have a bin n°34 composed by 6 pixels, because 34 appears 6 times, so I take all the stars whose positions (x,y) falls in this 6 pixel and take the mean value. Then I associate this mean value to all the 6 pixels which belong to bin 34).

I'm very grateful for your patience and your help!

Comment: It seems to work as I want! I have only a doubt: maybe in the key should be bins[index_for_{x}_rang_1, index_for_y_rang_1] ?

Comment: @K.B. Yes. You're right! I'll fix it on my answer too. Thanks :)

Comment: @K.B. There was also problems on the values of `start_x_rang_1`, `stop_x_rang_1`, ..., `step_y_rang_1` in my code. I fixed it too.